# What is the best way to set my controls height to a percentage of it's width in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I would like to set my WPF control's height to be a percentage of it's width.

I know that DevExpress makes this easy through it's DXBinding.

```
<Button Height="{DXBinding '@Self.ActualWidth*.65'}" />
```

What is the best way to achieve this in vanilla WPF?
One thought I had was to use a Converter.

I need to be able to pass the control's width and integer value (for scaling) as parameters
What would my XAML definition look like?

**XAML**

```
<Button Height="{Binding Path=MyWidth, Mode=OneWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                        ConverterParameter=65}" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    string parameterString = parameter as string;

    // value - contains the width of the control

    // parameter contains the desired scale percentage 
}
```

Is this viable?
Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: A Binding Converter is a good idea. Use a double value between 0 and 1 for the fraction: `ConverterParameter=0.65`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind to `Self.ActualHeigth` property like

```xml
<Button Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                         Path=ActualWidth,
                         Converter={StaticResource DoublePercentageConverter}, 
                         ConverterParameter=0.65}" />
```

and here the converter

```
public class DoublePercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        var factor = parameter switch
        {
            string v => double.TryParse( v, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var d ) ? d : 1.0,
            int v => System.Convert.ToDouble( v ),
            decimal v => System.Convert.ToDouble( v ),
            double v => v,
            _ => 1.0
        };

        return (double)value * factor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir Ruto: Perfect, Thx!